# Calculate the probability using Bayes' rule

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

**Case**
Scientists find that bacteria alpha occurs at $25\%$ of rainforests. If bacteria alpha is in fact present, there is a $50\%$ chance of detecting it in a search. Three searches fail to detect the bacteria alpha.

**Questions**
**1)** What is the probability that all three searches will fail to detect the bacteria, if in fact it is present?

Bayes' rule is given as  $$Pr(H_1|D)=\frac{P(D|H_1)*P(H_1)}{\sum P(D|H_j)*P(H_j)}$$

**2)** If the bacteria is recorded as absent in each of three searches, use Bayes' rule to calculate the posterior probability that it is in fact present at the site.

.

**My attempt**

For **question 1**, since there is a $50\%$ chance of detecting the bacteria, therefore there is also a $50\%$ of not detecting the species when it is present. Therefore

- $Pr$(not detecting when present)= $(1-0.5)^3$=0.125

Is this correct?

For **question 2**, I have no idea, can someone please show the working out for this question?

Thankyou for taking the time to read this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original, incorrect, analysis**

I'm not completely certain on what posterior probability means, but let's reason through this:

1. The search site *definitely* has the bacteria
  It is given that the probability of detection is $50\%$ given that the bacteria is present (which is the parameters of this case).  Therefore, indeed, it should be $0.5^3 = 0.125 = 12.5\%$.
2. You take a random sample (of the some place which *may or may not* contain the bacteria) and you *don't* detect the bacteria here.  There are two cases:

   1. The bacteria is present: $25\%$
     You don't detect it with a probability of $0.125$
   2. The baceteria is *not* present: $75\%$
     You don't detect the bacteria, assuming with a probability of $100\%$
     *given*
     that the bacteria is
     *not*
     there.

Combining those two gives a probability of the bacteria *being* there as: 
$$
0.25 * 0.125 + 0.75 * 1 = 0.78125 = 78.125\%
$$

For me the problem is that a false positive is *not* given (which is necessary).  Without a probability for false positive, I am assuming the probability of a false positive is $0\%$.

**Correct Analysis** (from comments)

\begin{align}
H_1 = &\text{no bacteria is present} \\
H_2 = &\text{bacteria is present} \\
D = & \text{three searches find no bacteria} \\
p(H_1 | D) =& \frac{p(D|H_1)*p(H_1)}{p(D|H_1)*p(H_1) + p(D|H_2)*p(H_2)}
\end{align}

We know $p(D|H_1) = 1$ (you said there were no false positives), $p(H_1) = 0.75$ ($75\%$ of rain forests contain bacteria), $p(D|H_2) = 0.125$ (probability of three false negatives give bacteria exists), and $p(H_2) = 0.25$ ($25\%$ of rain forests contain the bacteria).

This gives:

$$
p(H_1 | D) = \frac{0.75}{0.75 + 0.125 * 0.25} = 0.96 = 96\%
$$

I mispoke on my original answer (I implied the probability of there *not* being bacteria as fairly low--which is clearly counterintuitive--but I actually calculated the probability that *there was* bacteria).  If we change the above to calculate that we get:

$$
\frac{0.125 * 0.25}{0.125 * 0.25 + 1*0.75} = 0.04 = 4\%
$$

**Explain why my original analysis is incorrect**

Obviously what I did originally was wrong.  There are things wrong with my original analysis...I will leave it up to you and commenters to explain them.  Honestly, I think it will be helpful if I leave the incorrect analysis up.

Comment: Hi Jared,
Thankyou for your response. Given Bayes' rule 
$Pr(H_1|D)=\frac{P(D|H_1)*P(H_1)}{\sum P(D|H_j)*P(H_j)}$  
which values represents each parameter in Bayes' rule?

Comment: Yes the false positive is 0

Comment: Thankyou so much Jared, you've made that very clear! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to question 1 looks correct.

One possible approach to question 2 might be to consider $1$ million rainforests.

- How many do you expect to contain bacterium Alpha?
- How many do you expect ***not*** to contain bacterium Alpha?
- How many do you expect to contain bacterium Alpha but not to have bacterium Alpha detected in three searches?
- How many do you expect ***not*** to contain bacterium Alpha and not to have bacterium Alpha detected in three searches?
- How many do you expect in total not to have bacterium Alpha detected in three searches?
- What proportion do you expect of those which do not have bacterium Alpha detected in three searches actually contain bacterium Alpha?

Comment: Thankyou for your feedback Henry, this has taught me what to look for when calculating a problem like this

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ represent the number of times the bacteria is detected in $n$ searches, and $P$ represent the event that the bacteria is present.  Then the variable $X \mid P$ is binomial with parameters $n = 3$ and $p = 0.5$; and $X \mid \bar P$ is a degenerate distribution with $\Pr[X = 0 \mid \bar P] = 1$; that is to say, if no bacteria are present, we assume that the test will never detect its presence (no false positives).  Then question 1 asks for $$\Pr[X = 0 \mid P]$$ which is simply a binomial probability.

For question 2, we want $$\Pr[P \mid X = 0] = \frac{\Pr[X = 0 \mid P]\Pr[P]}{\Pr[X = 0]}.$$  The numerator is easy to calculate, but the denominator is a bit trickier.  The idea is to use the law of total probability and condition on whether the bacteria is present; i.e., $$\Pr[X = 0] = \Pr[X = 0 \mid P]\Pr[P] + \Pr[X = 0 \mid \bar P]\Pr[\bar P].$$